# Jemmy strucked at clickMouse() when notification dialog with progressbar are displayed

Tags: java, java-gui, jemmy

During autotest execution ([jemmy](/questions/tagged/jemmy) lib is used to interact with Java GUI elements) address data is entered and button 'Search for address' is pressed. At some addresses notification dialog with progressbar are displayed:

[image]

Code of `submitAddress` function:

```
public void submitAddress(JFrameOperator flsFrame) {
    // II
    JButtonOperator searchByAddressButton = new JButtonOperator(flsFrame, Chooser.chooseButtonByToolTipText("Открыть квартиру"));

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    searchByAddressButton.clickMouse();

    JTabbedPaneOperator tab = new JTabbedPaneOperator(flsFrame, 0);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("\nAddress has not been found within " + time + "ms\n");
}
```

When I set breakpoint on JtabbedPane initialization, execution pointer does not come to it untill I press OK on notification dialog. So the test is halting at `searchByAddressButton.clickMouse();`

I tried to set following timeouts to 5000 milliseconds but it was in vain ([full list of timeouts at jemmy.java.net](https://jemmy.java.net/OperatorsEnvironment.html)):

- **Test.WholeTestTimeout**
- ComponentOperator.WaitComponentTimeout
- ActionProducer.MaxActionTime
- DialogWaiter.WaitDialogTimeout
- EventDispatcher.WaitQueueEmptyTimeout
- EventDispatcher.WaitQueueEmptyTimeout
- QueueTool.WaitQueueEmptyTimeout
- QueueTool.LockTimeout
- ButtonOperator.PushButtonTimeout
- JProgressBarOperator.WaitValueTimeout

using the following code:

```
JemmyProperties.setCurrentTimeout("Test.WholeTestTimeout", 5000);
```

As you see even the whole test timeout does not help to identify that test is strucked at `searchByAddressButton.clickMouse();`

Any advices, suggestions?

#### Temporary solution

Set test execution timeout in [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) test annotation

```
@Test(timeOut = 30000)
public void testOpenFlsTabs() throws Exception {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `NoBlock` operation (`.pushNoBlock();`, `.pushMenuNoBlock("File|Open");`) with manually set timer `ComponentOperator.WaitComponentTimeout` and checking for any new component that should appear in GUI:

```
JemmyProperties.setCurrentTimeout("ComponentOperator.WaitComponentTimeout", 5000); // 5 seconds
...
searchByAddressButton.pushNoBlock();
new JTabbedPaneOperator(flsFrame, 0);   // check that new object has appeared (in 5 seconds)
```